# Exporting my Java program in Eclipse

Tags: java, deployment, executable, executable-jar

I have made a hello world program in eclipse and I was wondering how to run it out of eclipse (not on the console). I want to run it like you would with a `.exe`.  Is this possible?

Comment: This is not clear.  What do you mean by "not on the console"?

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html

Comment: The console is where you run your program. (Its called the console view)

Comment: If the app. is a desktop app., you are after either an executable Jar<sup>1</sup> or [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). 1. See the [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) lesson & particularly [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

Comment: Another alternative is to do this on the Command Prompt. You can read about doing it here. http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html

Comment: I have looked at that but it doesn't seem to work. I think this is because eclipse uses a "package name" and when you go to run it flags up an error

Comment: *"it flags up an error"*  Copy/paste the error is an edit to your question.  Nobody (including me) seems to quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you exported your program as an .exe, you would only be able to run it natively on Windows (the point of Java is that it is cross platform). You want to export it as a *Runnable JAR File*, which should be one of the export options in Eclipse:

[image]

By default, no console window will be opened when you try to open your JAR file, so any calls to `System.out` or `System.err` will be invisible. You can either run your JAR file through command prompt (`java -jar YourJarFile.jar`) or create a GUI for your user to interact with.